# How to resolve error: Could not identify Next.js version, ensure it is defined as a project dependency

Tags: vercel, sanity

I'm trying to deploy my project to vercel but getting this error:

*Warning: Could not identify Next.js version, ensure it is defined as a project dependency.
Error: No Next.js version could be detected in your project. Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies"*

Next JS is not in the root folder - How can I direct vercel to child folders?

My folder structure looks like this:

project

- web (Next JS)
- studio (Sanity Studio)